# Set JMS redelivery limit in Weblogic

Tags: jms, weblogic12c, message-driven-bean

I an using JMS in weblogic. If my MDB throws an exception, the message is redelivered. The problem I am trying to fix is set a message redelivery limit. Because the message deleivery does not stop. Goes over 300 times until I delete the entire deployment. I have done set message redelivery in JBOSS, but I am new to weblogic, and I want to set redelivery limit for this queue alone.

I have looks at this post here : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24387/implement.htm#JMSPG233
But that did not help.

Where do I set the max number of times this message should be delivered ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Redelivery Limit on WebLogic 12c is default to -1, which means it will try 2147483647 times before it give up. Try lower this value to something like 10, maybe.

You should search for this tab inside your queue and change the default value for Redelivery Limit.

[image: You should search for this tab inside your queue]

Hope it helps !

Comment: The queue is used by multiple producers/messages, hence I cannot change the redelivery on the queue itself. I want to change redelivery for a particular producer and leave the setting of -1 as is.

Comment: "-1, which means it will try 2147483647 times before it give up". In the documentation it says "The default value (-1) specifies that the destination will not override the message sender's redelivery limit setting". So -1 means it depends on the sender's value. It could be `2147483647` or it could be `1`